# Using a resource in a Jar

Tags: java, jar, getresource

I am well aware that this topic has been asked and answered more then a few times here, but I can't seem to get it to work and I think I need some fresh eyes to look at my project structure and code.

I have added a file into my resources folder and packed it in the JAR. I can see it there in the main level.
But every time I try to use it I get a **nullPointerException** and I suspect its because of the structure of the project.

[image]

from PDFToImage class I try to get the file like this:

```
File placeHolderSource = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(placeHolderFileName).getFile());
```

when `placeHolderFileName = "placeholder-greyed.jpg";`

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't get a `File` for a resource inside a jar file, because it's no longer a proper OS-level file in there (it's just a zip entry in a JAR file). If you **must** pass a `File` to some library (because it can't handle the `URL` or `InputStream` formats that you *can* get), then you need to read the resource and write it to some external (probably temporary) file and pass that name to the API.

Comment: @JoachimSauer it still fails. Now on the line `URL res = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(placeHolderFileName);` which i added just to see whats comming back.